# Gradle daemon unable to start jvm no Xmx1024 or any other error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I Have Tried A Many ways To Do Successful Gradle Build 
Tried A Lott Of Ways online But I can't Even I Have Changed `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx5124m`

To`org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m`

To

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx512m


    Unable to start the daemon process
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/4.4/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------

.
```

PC Info:
OS:Windows 8
Android Studio 3.1.4
Build #AI-173.4907809, built on July 23, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 8.1 6.3

Answer (score 0):

You can go to .gradle folder in your $USER_HOME and delete all the directories except wrapper. then build again in android studio and it will generate deamon again

Comment: It Worked Thanku